# What is difference between initialization of object using following code?

Tags: c#, .net

not understanding of defining methods , Following is the code

```
Person p = new person();
p = CreatePersonModel();
```

Here the `CreatePersonModel()` is creating person model in it.

but if i want to rewrite it using

```
Person p = CreatePersonModel();
```

it is also working fine. Then what is difference between 1 and 2nd approach.

Comment: The first snippet creates *two* objects and discards the first one. Use only the second

Comment: In the first example, you're completely throwing away the `new person();`. If this constructor has no side-effects, then it's just a waste of time. If it has side-effects, we can't say what the outcome is.

Comment: Only people who've started from a language like Visual Basic or C++ are allowed to downvote this question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I started with VB.NET and the book I read taught how to do it right at first. I don't know how many people I've had to taught not to follow this brilliant (`/s`) idea their c/c++/Java/C# professors teach them at some course.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto never mixed up Dim and New ? Or used `Dim A New` and later used another `New`? There are a lot of such beginner questions in SO. As for C++, the trick is that `Person p;` creates a new object. It's easy to get confused when just starting

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't remember a lot of VB.NET syntax right now, but I'm pretty sure I was very used to `Dim X As String = "bla"` (or similar). I followed the remark maid in Excercise A of this lesson (https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets1p12.html) and was never tempted to initialize twice something)

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach, you are creating a new person object and assigning it to `p`. Then, you are dereferencing the newly created object and assigned `p` to what ever `CreatePersonModel()` does.

The second approach, assigns `p` directly to whatever `CreatePersonModel()` returns.

The second approach allows you to avoid creating objects that will be immediately discarded, so the second option is usually preferred.

Other problems with the first approach could also be encountered if the `Person` object is slightly more complex, and might require other resources. This would make your application require more time and/or resources for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet creates *two* objects. One when `new` is called :

```
Person p = new person();
```

And another when the results of `CreatePersonModel()` get assigned to `p`.

```
p = CreatePersonModel();
```

The original value is lost and will be garbage collected. This is wasteful and should be avoided.

The second snippet only creates one object :

```
Person p = CreatePersonModel();
```

The equivalent, using type inference, is :

```
var p = CreatePersonModel();
```

Comment: And the equivalent, correctly typed, `var person = CreatePersonModel();`